# How to send notification when user is in an area?

Tags: android

I have an app that sends notifications when the user is in a specific area. I am implementing `LocationListener` and in `onLocationChanged` method I have something like this.

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Cursor cursor = new DatabaseHelper(this).getAll(); //Gets data from database


        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            double lat = Double.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL2)));
            double lon = Double.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL3)));


            float distance[] = new float[2];

            Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), lat, lon, distance);

//Notifications are sent from the below lines

            if (distance[0] <= Double.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL4)))) {


                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                builder.setContentTitle("You're nearby a reminder");
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                builder.setContentText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL1)) + " at " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL5)));

                builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(cursor.getPosition(), builder.build());
            }

        }

    }
```

The listener is called using `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);` and the program works fine but when the user moves the notification tone plays for every 10metres as it should.

Is there a way to play the notification sound only once until the notification is not cleared from the status bar?

Comment: You need to send notification when user enter in specific location

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to this problem is using the GeoFences feature. Please refer to https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html for more details.

Outline: - The application registers with the underlying OS - saying - here is MY list of geofences (specific location + radius from the location) that I want you to monitor. - If my user comes within this geo fence - wake me up and tell me so. - At that point of time - you can go ahead and perform any step (either call a server and ask what information you need to display to the user) or just send a push notification (in app notification) to do the necessary work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I looked into that as well but my app will have to work offline in this case.

Comment: If app offline can't know the location user you need to check every time the gps location updates to know the location.

Comment: GPS works offline buddy. My app is entirely offline. Haha. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Easy as pie it was. Lame for me to not read the Notification documentations.

```
            Notification compat = builder.build();
            compat.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(cursor.getPosition(), compat);
```

Just added `Notification.flag` and it does the trick.